# Cold-start a PushTopic with historical records

Tags: pushtopic

I have little experience with Salesforce, so excuse me if I'm not using the correct vocabulary.

I'm setting up a PushTopic to export Salesforce objects, and we have a connector that is consuming the PushTopic and putting the messages into a message-broker, where they are consumed by another application. However, to start off our consumer for this queue, we'd like to feed in all of the rows we already have in Salesforce. What's the best way to do this? I *could* write a script that uses the Salesforce bulk API and runs the same query as the PushTopic, transforms the results, and writes them to the message-broker. It would be less work and if we could 'tickle' the records in Salesforce to get the PushTopic to process them as if they were changed, and feed them through the same pipeline that future changes would come through.

Is there a recommended way to get past rows onto a PushTopic? Is there a risk of side-effects from 'tickling' the rows?

Answer (score 0):

Yes for initial retrieval of data, you will need to leverage `BULK API`, specifically [BULK API v2.0](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_bulk_v2.meta/api_bulk_v2/queries.htm) Queries to retrieve the data.

You will need to script this based on the language of your choice.

On Streaming API, I recommend you use CDC(Change Data Capture) or Platform events. These are more advanced compared to Streaming API. Read more [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/07/a-refresher-on-the-four-streaming-apis-and-a-monitoring-tool.html)

Also, it is important to pay attention to [limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_event_limits.htm) as you design the architecture.